# How to change the color of holoeverywhere tabs?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-holo-everywhere

The holoeverywhere's demo is like this:
[image]

How to change the background's color of the tabs and the color of line under the tabs?

Comment: I also want to change the color when click the tab, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Implementation of ActionBar  - ActionBarSherlock. Any hooks and actions which works with the ABS also works with HoloEverywhere. See [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/tree/master/actionbarsherlock-samples/styled).